# How to create progressive jpg on parse

Tags: parse-platform, jpeg, parse-cloud-code

I have a fairly large class on parse, with about 10,000(each of about 5mb, then generated smaller ones of about 300kb and 30kb) images and growing rapidly. I need to generate progressive jpegs for each image. Is there a way i could do this on parse cloud code?

As in:

```
jpegtran -progressive
```

Comment: I thought you need to create a background job to achieve the purpose.

Comment: is jpegtran available on parse?

Comment: No, you could check what parse-image module support in [parse-image module api](https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Image.html).

Comment: no supported :( thanks though. Looking to see possibility of adding such a lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse does not support this. You have to do this before uploading to Parse.